# VS Code Formatter braces on new line for css and scss

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, formatter

In VS Code formatter, searched a lot to format CSS and SCSS and put the braces in a new line as below, But dint find any. Can anyone help on this.

```
:root 
{
    --brandColorVar: #056ca1;
}

@font-face 
{
    font-family: Museo Sans;
    src: url("Font/MuseoSans_500.otf");
}

body 
{
    font-family: Museo Sans;
    margin: 0;
}

.NameCls 
{
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

I have found the setting for js but need the same for CSS too

```
"javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true, 
"javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,

"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
```